# How to apply SVD to real data to reduce the number of parameters?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank, svd

I have a question about applying the Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) to real data.  Say I have the equation 
$$ y= Ax+v$$
where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ is the noise.
And I want to estimate $x$, which are the parameters connecting measurements in $A$ to observations in $y$.

Let’s say I discover that my matrix $A$ has about 20 singular values which are significant, and then after that the singular values are miniscule (i.e. very small and insignificant).  And the matrix $A$ is $m=300k, n=10k$ so I have 300k observations in the vector $y$.

From what I understand, this means the following:

- Even though I can still construct the $300k$ observations in $y$ from the $A$ matrix, it has many measurements which don’t contribute much, so those should be removed.
- To fix this either:

  - Take SVD of the matrix $A,$ and only use the most significant parameters, i.e. the most significant 20.  This will slim down the A matrix and make it more skinny (reduce the number of columns in $A$).
  - Take more observations in a different, independent way, in addition to the 300k.  This will add rows to the $A$ matrix, and will add values to the $y$ vector.  See if it increase the number of significant singular values.  If so, take more measurements in that different, independent way.

My question is: If my understanding above is correct, then how will knowing which singular values are significant, tell me which parameters to keep, and which ones to throw away?  If I want to make the matrix $A$ skinnier and not use all 10k columns, then how do I know which columns correspond to the 20 most significant singular values?

This example was taken from about 62 minutes into Lecture 17 the Stanford course https://see.stanford.edu/Course/EE263/56 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you wouldn't be able to use a personal computer for that. The size of the matrix is enormous.  I am going to ignore the fact you typically care about the data. So people would typically use the PCA or something.

### General Formulation of the Problem

In general, the SVD is the following.

$$ A = U \Sigma V^{T}  \tag{1}$$

right, where $UU^{T} = U^{T}U =  I_{m} $ , $ VV^{T} = V^{T}V = I_{n} $ are orthogonal.
The singular values are actually given in descending order. That is

$$ \sigma_{1} \geq \sigma_{2} \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_{n} > 0 \tag{2} $$

If you have the following equation

$$ y = Ax+v \tag{3}$$

we can say

$$ y- v = Ax \implies U\Sigma V^{T}x = y-v \tag{4} $$

Now this simply turns into

$$ x = V \Sigma^{-1} U^{T}(y-v)  \tag{5} $$

Ok...right. If we want to apply a low rank approximation of $U \Sigma V^{T}$ we are simply choosing the $k$ largest singular values like the following.

$$ A_{k} = \sum_{i=1}^{k} \sigma_{i} u_{i} v_{i}^{t} \tag{6} $$

$$ A_{k} = U_{m \times k} \Sigma_{k \times k} V_{k \times n}^{T} \tag{7}$$

Note when take the inverse of $ \Sigma$  it is simply a diagonal matrix so we

$$ \Sigma^{-1} \implies \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}} \tag{8}  $$

Now we may not know the amount of noise in the signal. There are actually techniques for this. I think it is called Tikhonov Regularization. So you can introduce a regularization parameter $\lambda $.

I don't think I actually addressed how you would know. If you can do the following. Say take $k$ singular values and form a low rank approximation like above and the original matrix. We get this equation.

$$ \| A - A_{k} \|_{2} = \bigg\| \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \sigma_{i} u_{i} v_{i}^{t}\bigg\|_{2} = \sigma_{k+1} \tag{9} $$

If the $\sigma_{k+1} $ is relatively small for you then you may be happy.

In terms of real world data this doesn't really hold what happens when you apply the SVD. You'd have to look into the principal components analysis. That is if you are thinking that first 20 columns are still: red, blue, length of hair. They aren't. They are linear combinations that are orthogonalized. The data transformations are called the principal components.

Tikhonov Regularization looks like this

$$ \hat{x} = \min_{x} \| y- Ax \|_{2}^{2} + \|\Gamma x \|_{2}^{2} \tag{10}$$

where $ \Gamma$ is a matrix

### For your questions

> Even though I can still construct the 300k observations in y from the
>   A matrix, it has many measurements which don’t contribute much, so
>   those should be removed.

This is correct. There is likely some relationship you could come up with between the data and your measurements but adding more measurements wouldn't do any good. This is an area of research called inverse problem theory.

> If I want to make the matrix A skinnier and not use all 10k columns,
>   then how do I know which columns correspond to the 20 most significant
>   singular values?

### Where the SVD comes from

Part of the problem with the SVD is what it does. If you just want to look at this from the minimizing error aspect you can use the SVD. The principal component analysis is another method which is the statiscal cousin of the SVD. One way of understanding this is actually understanding how the SVD is computed. If I have a data matrix $A$ then the SVD is the actually formed from the eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix $A^{T}A$

$$ A^{T}A = (U \Sigma V^{T})^{T} U \Sigma V^{T} \tag{11}$$

$$ A^{T}A = V \Sigma^{T} U^{T} U \Sigma V^{T} \tag{12}$$

using orthogonality

$ U^{T}U = UU^{T} = I_{m} $

$$ A^{T}A = V \Sigma^{T} \Sigma V^{T} \tag{13}$$

also we know

$ \Sigma^{T} \Sigma = \Sigma \Sigma^{T} = \Lambda $

$$ A^{T}A = V \Lambda V^{T} \tag{14}$$

Similarly

$$ AA^{T} = U \Lambda U^{T} \tag{15}$$

### Low rank Approximation

I think there was some trouble understanding what it means to make a low-rank approximation. I can do this fairly easily. Say we construct a matrix randomly in Python that is rank-deficient.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m=10
n=m
k=5


def gen_rank_k(m,n,k):
# Generates a rank k matrix
# Input m: dimension of matrix
# Input n: dimension of matrix
# Input k: rank of matrix

    vec1 = np.random.rand(m,k)
    vec2 = np.random.rand(k,n)
    rank_k_matrix = np.dot(vec1,vec2)

    return rank_k_matrix

A = gen_rank_k(m,n,k)
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(A, full_matrices = False)

x = np.linspace(1,10,10)

plt.plot(x,s)

my_rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)
```

If you wanted to visualize the singular values [image]

Note our command above..

```
my_rank = np.linalg.matrix_rank(A)

my_rank
Out[9]: 5
```

how do you choose them? You can do it fairly simply like this.

```
def low_rank_k(u,s,vh,num):
# rank k approx

    u = u[:,:num]
    vh = vh[:num,:]
    s = s[:num]
    s = np.diag(s)
    my_low_rank = np.dot(np.dot(u,s),vh)
    return my_low_rank
```

This part here is

$$ A_{k} = U_{m \times k} \Sigma_{k \times k} V_{k \times n}^{T} \tag{16}$$

```
my_rank_k = low_rank_k(u,s,vh,5)

my_error = np.linalg.norm(A-my_rank_k)
```

This part is

$$ \| A - A_{k} \|_{2} = \bigg\| \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} \sigma_{i} u_{i} v_{i}^{t}\bigg\|_{2} = \sigma_{k+1} \tag{17} $$

```
my_error
Out[7]: 6.541665918732523e-15
```

now if you look $k=5$ what is $\sigma_{k+1} = \sigma_{6}$

```
s[6]
Out[6]: 3.8119202900864143e-16
```

### Some other visuals

There is some other visuals for a reduced SVD versus a full SVD

[image]

[image]

if you note that section there is all $0$. The interpretation is you form these $20$ components $U\Sigma$ . The coefficients in the vectors tell you how much of each predictor you are using and the singular values $\sigma$ are telling you the magnitude in the direction of the orthogonal component it goes. Visually like above.

[image]

If you look at these singular values they decay.

### Creating Pseudo Inverse

Technically to generate the pseudo inverse $A^{\dagger}$ we should do the following. The $\sigma_{i}$ past the rank are going to blow up because they are not $0$

Choose parameter $\epsilon$. Now we can form the matrix $\Sigma^{\dagger}$ like this.

$$ \Sigma^{\dagger}  =\begin{align}\begin{cases} \frac{1}{\sigma_{i}} &  \sigma_{i} \leq \epsilon \\  0     &   \sigma_{i} > \epsilon    \end{cases} \end{align} \tag{18}$$

Which gives us

$$A^{\dagger} = V \Sigma^{\dagger} U^{T} \tag{19} $$

Comment: Thanks, thats a lot of data

Comment: I'm afraid this is missing my question though.  I'm asking - *If I know that there are 20 significant singular values, then how do I use that information to reduce the number of observations taken, or the numberof parameters, used to approximate y?*  If you watch the lecture I linked to, at like 62 minutes, it will make my question more clear. (https://see.stanford.edu/Course/EE263/56)

Comment: it's currently like 2 am, I will update this sometime when I wake up with some code most likely.

Comment: also if you look it is tag 7 the SVD should only have up to the kth singular value. it is called the truncated singular value decomp. it is a typical command you can called. when you call svd in python or matlab one of the parameters is whether is full or not. it will return it as truncated.

Comment: Yes, I can take the $k^{th}$ approximation of the data.  However, as I was saying, that still seems to require taking all 10k measurements, and then projecting them into a lower dimensional space **after** the data has been collected.  But if you watch the lecture (_please_ watch it at 59 minutes)  then you'll hear the professor say _because there are only 20 significant singular values, "they thought they took 300 thousand measurements and in fact, they didn't know it but they actually took only 20"_.   I do not understand this statement.

Comment: Sorry I was just about to come upstairs and write something. One moment.

Comment: Just watch the lecture it will really help.

Comment: This still isn't answering my question -  _how do I choose amongst the 10k which measurements to keep_?

Comment: https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-12-11-pca-explained-variance. The singular values are ordered. You're attempting to explain the "variance" of data with the principal components. Only a few of these are needed. They are ordered. They are leading ones. You are not choosing random singular values or random measurements. 

You actually don't have 20 measurements..you have a linear combination of the measurements. the singular value decomp is using the QR decomposition. It'd be best if you performed the SVD on a small matrix.

Comment: https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779576344458/singular-value-decomposition-fast-track-tutorial.pdf if you look at this tutorial..you'll see what is happening and what happens when you have a rank deficient matrix.

Comment: Yes I understand that the SVD/PCA finds orthogonal components to explain the data.  But those are a linear combination of *all* of the regressors - not a subset.  Even if there is only one significant singular value, it can be a linear combination of all of the other 10k features/regressors.  So I'm asking how do I know, out of all of those 10k, which ones to keep. (and then same question for 2nd significant singular value, and 3rd, etc.)  They all contribute.  How do I know which ones to keep?

Comment: It's a somewhat different question. If you want to determine which predictors to keep there is something called variance inflation factor for determining multicollinearity of predictors. You drop predictors with variance inflation factor over 10.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor

Comment: Right...I've used that technique before.  It doesn't require the use of SVD at all.  So, I'm **_still_** wondering why the lecture says that you can reduce the 10k regressors by knowing that there are 20 significant singular values.  It doesn't tell us how to choose the subset of those 10k.  Now do you see what I'm asking?  This seems to have nothing to do with the singular values (similar to the VIF - no singular values mentioned there), hence my confusion.  If you watch the lecture, it will really help clarify my question.

Comment: I've updated with some code. You can fool around with it. note that the singular values are essentially $1e-16$ or zero past the rank of the matrix which mean they contribute nothing to it.  now think about what happens when you take those vectors and approximate a matrix with them.